# Equivalent conditions for $f$ to be a quotient map.

Tags: general-topology, continuity, quotient-spaces

I am reading the book 'Algebraic Topology' by T.T. Dieck, and am confused by one of his results in the opening chapter. He claims:

Proposition 1.2.3

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a surjective continuous map between spaces. Then the following are equivalent:

1) $f$ is a quotient map

2) A set map (i.e. not necessarily continuous) $g:Y\to Z$ to any other topological space $Z$ is continuous if and only if $gf$ is continuous.

So $1)\Rightarrow 2)$ is easy. For $2)\Rightarrow 1)$, if you set $Z=Y$ and take $g=Id_Y$, then $gf=f$ is continuous since $Id_Y$ is continuous. It therefore remains to show $U$ is open in $Y$ if the preimage $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$. However, here I am stuck. Obviously if $f$ is an open map then the result is immediate, but I don't think Dieck is assuming this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying (2) for a $g$ which is known to be continuous will not suffice.

However, we can correct your reasoning with $g=id_Y$ by considering once the topology given on $Y$,  and secondly the quotient topology  induced by $f$, put on $Z$ (where $Z=Y$ as set).

Since $f:X\to Y$ is continuous and surjective, $Y$ will have a coarser topology than the quotient topology: $\tau_Y\subseteq\tau_Z$. 
But the identity $Y\to Z$ is also continuous by (2), so $Y$ has a finer topology: $\tau_Z\subseteq\tau_Y$. 
So, $\tau_Y=\tau_Z$, i.e. as topological spaces, $Y=Z$. $\quad\quad$ -*QED*-

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Firstly, why can I not take a specific space $Z$ to show $f$ is continuous? Since 2) holds for any space $Z$, then in particular it holds when $Z=Y$. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: Yes, you can take $Z=Y$, and actually it will suffice. But you will have to consider 2 different topologies, namely put the quotient topology on $Z$.

Comment: Explicitly: $\tau_Z$ contains all $V\subseteq Y$ for which $f^{-1}(V)$ is open in $X$ (i.e. $\in\tau_X$).

Comment: Ah yes of course. Thank you